# Недодумка хака вызывает капчу у всех юзеров

Tags: android, vkontakte-api

Всем добрый вечер. Необходимо сделать получение популярной музыки и ее поиск с помощью VK API. Как я понял, мне нужны методы `audio.getPopular` и `audio.search`. Единственный трабл - вк орет ошибкой #5 так как юзер не вошел, токена нет, а он нужен.

**Что я сделал?**

- Создал левый акк вк
- Вошел в него, токен записал в ресурсы
- При входе если юзер не вошел я записываю в `preferences` с тем же ключом `VK_SDK_ACCESS_TOKEN_PLEASE_DONT_TOUCH` токен фейка.
- Выходит, что я получаю популярные, просто юзеру не показываю, пишу, что "Вы не вошли".

Вообщем, минус хака

- Токен, выходит, один на всех юзеров. Все юзеры получают капчу, потому что слишком бурная активность с одного токена с разных точек России. Как этот хак допилить, чтоб он работал? Если никак, то как получить популярную музыку и юзать поиск **без токена**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вынесите токен на бэкэнд. Сделайте получение списка популярной музыки по крону, скажем, раз в час. Результаты кэшируйте, например, в базе данных. Затем уже из приложения делайте запрос к бэкэнду и получайте от него список популярной музыки.

Comment: С поиском беда?

Comment: @Flippy, не понял.

Comment: Ну, поиск же динамичный процесс. Нельзя же всю музыку на сервере держать...

Comment: @Flippy, так вы не музыку, а ID аудиозаписей храните. А там уж был какой-то метод, которым можно было бы получить информацию об аудиозаписи по её ID.